# how do I make eclipse not add javadoc tags in new method comments?

Tags: java, eclipse

In my Eclipse configuration, when I create a new method comment, it doesn't add  javadoc tags.  This is how I want it.  A colleague of mine gets javadoc tags added to the comment when he creates the comment initially.  He wants it to be configured like me.  I can't remember how I did this.  I thought it might be in the formatter, but I don't see anything in there that would control this.

**Update**:

Note that a workaround for this is to edit each Code Template in the "Code Style" section that references javadoc tags.  That's a little annoying.  I never did that.  Whatever I did to get it this way, I never edited those templates.  I don't want that to be the solution.

Comment: A picture of each actual & expected will help to understand what you are asking for  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you are asking for.

> Windows >> Preferences >> Java >> Editor >> Typing >> Automatically Close >> Javadoc and comment regions >> Uncheck `Add Javadoc tags`.

Comment: That was it.  I actually had that turned on, but I realized I just manually delete the javadoc tags.  This makes it easier.